# Setting background-color property just for the centered body

Tags: html, css, background-color

I would like to know how to change the background-colour, but just of the center of the body. How is that possible?

```
    html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;

}

body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

The background-color command here is changing the colour of the whole website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll need to post some code

Comment: you could center a div inside the body and change its background colour or you could use css3 gradient and target the middle for a certain colour well leaving the rest white or w.e other colour

Comment: thank you droppel, that has solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

So your question is quite vague so I'm not entirely sure I know what you're asking.

BUT - What I think you're asking for is this... **http://jsfiddle.net/x6kVH/**

What you'd need to do is create a container to put your content inside

```
<div id="container">
<!-- ALL CONTENT GOES IN HERE -->
</div>

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    background:
    #ff0000; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```